# Set PHP form array variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm currently in the process of passing a javascript array though to a form for submission with a file upload.

As it currently stands i have been able to pass the javascript array though to the form but not quite how i would like.

The initial javascript values i have stored in the array are as follows:

```
Folder 1/File 1.txt
Folder 1/Folder 2/File 2.txt
```

Once passed though the array output from the PHP variable is as follows:

`Array ( [0] => Folder 1/File 1.txt,Folder 1/Folder 2/File 2.txt )`

What i would like to do however if possible is alter the array to the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Folder 1/File 1.txt, 
        [1] => Folder 1/Folder 2/File 2.txt )
```

The HTML code the array is being passed to from javascript:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pathArray" name="pathArray[]" value="pathArray">
```

The current javascript code:

```
    let picker = document.getElementById('picker');
    var pathStructure = [];
    var i = 0;
                                    
    picker.addEventListener('change', e =>
    {
        for (let file of Array.from(e.target.files))
        {
            pathStructure[i] = file.webkitRelativePath;
            i++;
        };

        document.getElementById('pathArray').value = pathStructure.toString();
    });
```

The main issue i'm having and at the moment is setting the array position values of the form for submission. I'm able to input the array into the form but not able to set the individual array positions and as of yet have been unable to find the relevant documentation on how to achieve this somehow like the following:

```
let picker = document.getElementById('picker');
var pathStructure = [];
var i = 0;

picker.addEventListener('change', e =>
{
    for (let file of Array.from(e.target.files))
    {
        pathStructure[i] = file.webkitRelativePath;
        document.getElementById('pathArray').value[i] = pathStructure[i].toString();
        i++;
    };
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if at all there is any further detail that would be required please let me know and i'll do my best to expand or provide any additional information!

Answer (score 0):

`toString` method joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas. So you lose the array information.

I usually did something like this with adding multiple inputs:

```html
<form id="form">
<input type="hidden" class="pathArray" name="pathArray[]">
<input type="hidden" class="pathArray" name="pathArray[]">
...
</form>
```

The idea is that for each value you create a new input. You will have input for `Folder 1/File 1.txt`, another input for `Folder 2/File 2.txt` and so on. The final code could look something like this

```js
let picker = document.getElementById('picker');
var pathStructure = [];
var i = 0;

picker.addEventListener('change', e =>
{
    for (let file of Array.from(e.target.files))
    {
        pathStructure[i] = file.webkitRelativePath;
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = 'pathArray[]';
        input.classList.add('pathArray');
        document.getElementById("form").appendChild(input);
        document.getElementsByClassName('pathArray')[i].value = pathStructure[i].toString();
        i++;
    };
});
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for that.

That certainly is one option, i'll give it a whirl and see what i think!